# Why is GMOL dead frozen at $0.03 since last 1 week?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

Can anybody explain why General Moly (GMOL) stock is trading at $0.03 since 1 week? I want to understand if its better to sell the GMOL stocks I have or wait? In some stock trading websites, the tickr still shows as GMO which is again confusing.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this help? http://www.generalmoly.com/investors/news/

Comment: Specifically - "General Moly Files Chapter 11 to Pursue Financial and Operational Reorganization; Several Directors Resign Their Positions and Interim CEO Named; Toronto Stock Exchange Suspends Listing of Common Stock Pending Delisting Review"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you see the price frozen is that trading for the stock has been halted since November 17.

[November 18 Press Release](http://www.generalmoly.com/news-release/general-moly-files-chapter-11-to-pursue-financial-and-operational-reorganization-several-directors-resign-their-positions-and-interim-ceo-named-toronto-stock-exchange-suspends-listing-of-common-sto/)

> The Company also received a letter from the Toronto Stock Exchange (the "TSX") on November 17, 2020, indicating that trading of the Company's common stock on the TSX had been suspended pending a review of the eligibility for continued listing of the Company's common stock. The TSX's Continued Listing Committee will meet on November 26, 2020 to consider whether or not to delist the Company's common stock pursuant to the TSX's delisting criteria relating to insolvency or bankruptcy proceedings (Section 708) and financial condition and/or operating results (Sections 709 and 710(a)(i)).
>
> The OTC Pink Open Market also halted trading in the Company's common stock on November 17, 2020.